# Graph Visualization using GraphViz

Tags: c++, graphviz, minimum-spanning-tree, graph-visualization, kruskals-algorithm

Playing around graph theory, I implemented Kruskal's algorithm in C++ and used GraphViz for visualization but on running the code to generate the png file with the command :

```
circo -Tpng PairPQ.cpp -o graph.png
```

It shows this :

```
Error: PairPQ.cpp:7: syntax error near line 7
context:  >>> using <<<  namespace std;
Warning: non-terminated HTML string starting line 36, file PairPQ.cpp
```

I'm using ubuntu linux to do this and attached below is my c++ code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

**7** using namespace std;

template <typename X, typename Y>

class PairPQ {
  pair<X, Y> i;
  int r;

public:
  PairPQ(const X x, const Y y, const int rank)
    : i(x, y),
      r(rank) {
  }

  const pair<X, Y>& item(void) const {
    return i;
  }

  int rank(void) const {
    return r;
  }

**36** bool operator < (const PairPQ& other) const {
    return r < other.r;
  }
};

int find_set(const int u, vector<int>& parent) {
  // check if at root
  if (parent[u] == u)
    return u;

  // not at root, chase upwards and set parent to ultimate root
  return parent[u] = find_set(parent[u], parent);
}

void link_set(const int u,
              const int v,
              vector<int>& parent,
              vector<int>& depth) {
  if (depth[u] < depth[v]) {
    parent[u] = v;
  } else {
    parent[v] = u;
    if (depth[u] == depth[v])
      depth[u]++;
  }
}

void union_set(const int u,
               const int v,
               vector<int>& parent,
               vector<int>& depth) {
  link_set(find_set(u, parent),
           find_set(v, parent),
           parent,
           depth);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // input number of vertices and edges
  cout << "input number of vertices and edges" << endl;
  int V, E;
  cin >> V >> E;

  // check for maximum number of possible edges (disallow anti-parallel arcs)
  if (E > V*(V-1)/2) {
    E = V*(V-1)/2;
    cout << "warning, maximum number of possible edges is " << E << endl;
  }

  // construct random weighted graph
  vector<vector<int> > G(V, vector<int>(V, 0));
  for (int i = 0; i < E; i++)
    while (true) {
       const int u = rand() % V,
                v = rand() % V;

      // no self loops
      if (u != v)
        // disallow anti-parallel edges and overwriting existing arcs
        if (0 == G[v][u] && 0 == G[u][v]) {
          G[u][v] = 1 + rand() % 100;
          break;
        }
    } 

  // union-find sets are implemented inside the arrays
  vector<int> parent(V, 0), depth(V, 0);

  // at the start, all nodes point to themselves
  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    parent[i] = i;
    depth[i] = 0;
  }

   // load all edges into priority queue, smallest weight on top of max-heap
   priority_queue<PairPQ<int, int> > PQ;
   for (int u = 0; u < V; u++)
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
      if (G[u][v])
        PQ.push(PairPQ<int, int>(u, v, -G[u][v]));

  // keep track of MST edges
  set<int> MSTedges;

  // loop over all edges in ascending order of weight
  while (!PQ.empty()) {
    // no need for lazy decrease key idiom here!
    const int u = PQ.top().item().first,
              v = PQ.top().item().second;
    // (don't care about rank/weight, note too that direction does not matter)
     PQ.pop();

    // check for edge between disjoint sets
    if (find_set(u, parent) != find_set(v, parent)) {
      MSTedges.insert(u * V + v);
      union_set(u, v, parent, depth);
    }
  }

  // print MST graph in GraphViz format
  cout << endl
       << "To generate a GraphViz graph from the following, do:" << endl
       << endl
       << "  circo -Tpng file_with_graph_G -o graph.png" << endl
       << endl
       << "-----file_with_graph_G begins here-----" << endl
       << "graph G {" << endl
       << "  node [shape=circle]" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < V; j++) {
      const int w = max(G[i][j], G[j][i]);
      if (w) {
        cout << "  " << i << " -- " << j
             << " [label=\"" << w << "\"";
        if (MSTedges.count(i * V + j) || MSTedges.count(j * V + i))
          cout << ",color=red";
         cout << "];" << endl;
      }
    }
  cout << "}" << endl;

  exit(0);
}
```

I assume my namespacing isn't wrong or any other way to go about this?

Comment: Is `circo` really supposed to compile c++ code??

Comment: Why do you expect graphviz to make a graph from a `C++` source file? You need a description of the graph in dot language for graphviz to interpret it properly. You are missing a vital step.

Comment: @saopayne `circo` is a layout engine, it cannot possibly interpret `C++`. http://www.graphviz.org/category/graphviz-terms/circo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it looks like you should be compiling this C++ program with a C++ compiler (of course) like GCC, and then when you run the program, it will generate a GraphViz graph, which you can *then* feed to `circo`. `circo` has no idea what to do with your C++ file by itself.

Something like this:

```
$ g++ PairPQ.cpp -o PairPQ
$ ./PairPQ > MyGraph
$ circo -Tpng MyGraph -o graph.png
```